# error Bad request for field slot 0,-1

Tags: android, sqlite, error-handling

i am working on an android database application and have fired query like this

```
public Cursor strok(String holid, String gameId2) throws SQLException  {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{



                abc = db.rawQuery("select MAX(strokeNo) from extended where "
                         + " holeId = " + holid + "  and " + " courseId = " + gameId2+";"
                          ,null);

                    }

                catch(Exception e)

                       {

                          Log.e("ERROR OF HOLE ID IS ",  e.toString());
                           e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        System.out.println("hello " + abc);

                return abc;
        }
```

and receiving in the activity like this

```
  Cursor cursor = db.strok(HoleIds.get(n),gameId);

                    System.out.println("after query ");

                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                startManagingCursor(cursor);

                System.out.println("the recived value is " +cursor);

        String maxs = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("strokeNo"));
                    System.out.println("the recived value is " +maxs);

but it is giving an error which i have not been able to find it out
```

the log cat is

```
03-20 11:43:43.396: E/CursorWindow(6138): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1
03-20 11:43:43.396: E/ERROR OF HOLE ID IS(6138): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
03-20 11:43:43.396: W/System.err(6138): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
03-20 11:43:43.526: W/System.err(6138):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
03-20 11:43:43.526: W/System.err(6138):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
03-20 11:43:43.526: W/System.err(6138):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
03-20 11:43:43.526: W/System.err(6138):     at golf.score.project.ExtendedScoreDisplay.onCreate(ExtendedScoreDisplay.java:123)
03-20 11:43:43.536: W/System.err(6138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-20 11:43:43.556: W/System.err(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-20 11:43:43.556: W/System.err(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-20 11:43:43.556: W/System.err(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-20 11:43:43.556: W/System.err(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-20 11:43:43.567: W/System.err(6138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 11:43:43.577: W/System.err(6138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-20 11:43:43.598: W/System.err(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-20 11:43:43.598: W/System.err(6138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 11:43:43.606: W/System.err(6138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-20 11:43:43.606: W/System.err(6138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-20 11:43:43.606: W/System.err(6138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-20 11:43:43.606: W/System.err(6138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i want to know where the error is and how to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 abc = db.rawQuery("select MAX(strokeNo) from extended where "
                         + " holeId = " + holid + "  and " + " courseId = " + gameId2+";"
                          ,null);
```

when it comes to where clause in Sql, you should know String must be surrounded by '.

```
abc = db.rawQuery("select MAX(strokeNo) from extended where "
                         + " holeId = '" + holid + "'  and " + " courseId = '" + gameId2+"';"
                          ,null);
```

EDITED:

As in your sql query you had select only one field so cursor will have only one field

```
String maxs = cursor.getString(0);
```

Comment: had you seen that the query which you asked for having a record in database?

Comment: i printed that quey in logcat and and fired it in command prompt it is working fine there

Comment: 03-20 12:33:26.207: I/System.out(13719): select MAX(strokeNo) from extended where  holeId = 1  and  courseId =  1;

Comment: what i am asking, is there any record which matches you condition? it might be possible there no Strokeno which contain holeid and courseid which you passed.

Comment: there are values in that table contain holeid and courseid which i passed

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked can you tell what could be the reason for that error

Comment: its because in select field you had selected only(strokeno) not select * from....,

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem in your code. You are using

`abc = db.rawQuery("select MAX(strokeNo) from extended where "
    + " holeId = " + holid + "  and " + " courseId = " + gameId2+";"
     ,null);
}`

And using 
`cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("strokeNo"))`
to retrieve the value. But there is no such column `strokeNo` in the resultant cursor.

You should use `cursor.getString(0);` instead. This should work fine.

There is another solution. You can change your query to

`abc = db.rawQuery("select MAX(strokeNo) as maxstroke from extended where "
    + " holeId = " + holid + "  and " + " courseId = " + gameId2+";"
     ,null);
}`

and while retrieving use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("maxstroke"))`. I think this will solve your problem.